# What are the benefits of space research and explorations to common people?

Tags: space

Suppose, a country's government has enough revenue to undertake space research and space exploration missions. It doesn't have any space program.

What kind of benefits would space research and explorations bring to the common people of that country?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [*Why is India diverting its resources to build its second mission to Mars?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/68990)

Comment: Related question on Space SE: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37496/

Comment: Do you want to know about benefits of space research done anywhere or are you interested in the situation of various other countries already doing space research, what benefits are there for an additional country to join in?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because The question asks us to "exclude political [...] benefits" putting it off topic on this forum about politics.

Comment: You're asking two very different questions: "What's the _government_'s motivation"  and "What's in it for _common people_". Decide which of them you want answers about.

Comment: @einpoklum, the second one.

Comment: What are the benefits of science? Or, what is the net effect of having science done by government? If you had asked the second question it would be a politics question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's *necessarily* not all that much benefit, *at a national level* for *any given* country.  Though *some* might benefit.  A large, rich country can afford a space program, a poorer or smaller country might put the money to better use elsewhere.

Making claims about space benefits *in general* is missing the point:  a given country can purchase space services from elsewhere (say weather sat reports or crop surveillance).  Even launch services for your own country's satellites are widely available.  And tech breakthroughs from space are mostly available on the free market.

On the other hand, a country with a large engineering and scientific base may very well benefit from building competency in the space domain.

And some countries may not find it easy, or a good idea, to buy space services off-the-shelf:  China's aim to be great power precludes that and North Korea isn't going to be able to buy it.

So it really depends and that's also a bit like building your own military hardware:  there's only place for so many national space programs that bring something new to the table rather than being *me too*s.  All the more if you want to sell launch services - those are hugely competitive, on cost and reliability metrics.  That's especially true now that rocket tech is evolving so quickly - even established players like Arianespace are being put under pressure, doubly so the Russian program.

But it's not like countries are never known to engage in prestige projects - that's why the term "white elephant" was invented after all.  You see this time and again in advanced fields like car manufacturing, jet airliners, etc... Those are rarely *obviously* a waste in a well-run country, but they still happen.

At another level, there's opportunity for a nice lil bit of space pork too:  NASA's SLS for example is years late, billions over budget, will cost ma$$ive per launch.  How many Webbs could have built with it?  But it will doubtless be defended tooth and nail by lobbyists and congress people:  you can mix worthwhile and wasteful programs within the same country.

Last, rather than going all in on your *own space program* - your own spaceports, your own launchers, your own satellites and deep space probes, you may very well reap good benefits from participating in collaborative programs with others - there's ample space to do so.

(Even though this is a political forum, it doesn't seem unreasonable to discount political reasons, in order to discern if citizens and taxpayers are being sold a dud, *for political reasons*).

Answer (score 5):

Even if there were NO practical benefits, (which I'll show you later there are money) all science begins theoretically. For eg. when Faraday pioneered electromagnetic devices which is used in so many devices such as Car motors, he was asked what it's practical use was, he didn't know.

Other than that space exploration leads to many good impacts for the people. Consumer products like wireless headsets, LED lighting, portable cordless vacuums, freeze-dried foods, memory foam, scratch-resistant eyeglass lenses all of them were derived from space race technology. Increased standard of living, more scientific opportunities for education/employment etc. are just few of so many good reasons to invest in space exploration.

Comment: And don't forget the countless satellites in Earth orbit which provide all kinds of direct and indirect benefits to citizens. Like accurate weather predictions, TV or GPS. Yes, many of them are privately owned, but they would not exist if government-sponsored space exploration in the 50s and 60s hadn't showed that they are possible.

Comment: I was never convinced by the "space exploration is good because look at the discoveries that have trickled down to everyday living" argument. For one, regardless of how many space-related inventions you'll list, the number will be dwarfed by the number of inventions that don't have any relation to space exploration. Also, even if the development of e.g. wireless headsets has been sped up by space exploration, it's not a given that we wouldn't have them by now even without that accelerator. There's a clear need for wireless audio equipment, and this need would have fueled innovation anyways.

Comment: @Schmuddi don't look at the raw number of "space inventions" vs "non-space inventions", but compare the amount weighted to how much money is being spent. Yes, the budgets of space agencies *sound* big, because *all* national agency budgets *sound* big.

Comment: @Caleth: I don't grudge the space agencies their budget – after all, I also work in an academic field that is exclusively funded from public sources. My point is not that the number of "space inventions" is too small to justify the budget, my point is that I question the (unfalsifiable) claim that without space programs, a noticeable number of inventions that improve every-day life would have never been made, and that our lives would be the worse because of it.

Comment: @Schmuddi "regardless of how many space-related inventions you'll list, the number will be dwarfed by the number of inventions that don't have any relation to space exploration." Why do the benefits of one sphere of R&D have to approach *the sum total of all other development in society* in order to count as significant? Your general point makes sense, but that's an absurd comparison to make; by that logic we can dismiss each and every research program individually because the number of inventions that come out of it are dwarfed by the number of inventions that don't have any relation to it.

Comment: @Ben: I don't want to invalidate space-related research – but I'm not buying that particular argument. Of course do other spheres of R&D produce side products that may end up in every-day life, and and of course is the proportion of these inventions in relation to the overall number of inventions not a good yardstick to justify these spheres. And yet – it's an argument frequently brought up *especially* to justify space-related programs. But on what basis? Have these programs yielded an *especially* large number of marketable inventions? I doubt that they have, hence this comparison.

Comment: LEDs were not invented by govt.  Freeze dried food ditto.  As to the rest, the claim is these things would not have existed without govt running them. A claim not in evidence, and having massive evidence the other way.

Comment: @Schmuddi Think of the automotive industry vs the horse and buggy industry. What tech came about research into automotive that would not have otherwise advanced? Plenty. More than just researching the tech, its development. Too many people forget that development brought many of these products to market. Not just by inventing them, but purchasing them from manufacturers that create processes to adapt them to mass market. There are many life-changing inventions that never made it beyond prototype. The space programs bring a subset of prototypes to market.